# MySQL zip installation defaults file my.ini could not open during the installation

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a program that installs MySQL from zip file.
Program can extract files from zip file to the Program Files folder and create an option file in Program Files folder for mysql called "my.ini".

After the extraction process, program is gonna initialize data folders and files via run the mysqld.exe.

The program run the mysqld.exe via `Process.Start()` with some arguments. The arguments are 
`--defaults-file=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\my.ini --initialize-insecure --console`.

When I try to run mysqld.exe with that arguments, it throws an error like;

```
mysqld: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file: C:\Program
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

My codes are like below;

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = destPath + "\\bin";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = destPath + "\\bin\\mysqld.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "--defaults-file=" + destPath + "\\my.ini --initialize-insecure --console";
        p.OutputDataReceived += P_OutputDataReceived;
        p.Start();

        // destPath:"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL"
```

Comment: Quote the path as it has spaces: `"--defaults-file=\"" + destPath + "\\my.ini\" --initialize-insecure --console"`

Comment: You may right but when I try to read option file under the Windows folder like the same, there is no error. I didn't understand what is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. my.ini file must places to paths like below;

[image]

More information can be found below
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html